# using proguard to obfuscate android library using android studio

Tags: android, obfuscation

My requirement is to obfuscate an android library using Proguard and then study behaviour of the obfuscated code that is generated. I made the changes in my module's build.gradle and when I build my lib, I get a build folder inside my module folder. In that build folder, I have the output generated. In intermediate folder(inside module>build) I get all the obfuscated java files(class files). But when I open these files outside android studio, I see there is a large difference but when opened inside android studio, they are opening as the same java files(as in no obfuscation visible at all). I am confused as to what is the correct way to go about this entire process. Also, if I need to study how the string variables are obfuscated. Need pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in gridle you will used it

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain the purpose of using the above code .

Comment: shrinkResources used for unused resource hide and progouad used for optimization purpose

Comment: Well, I was using the above in my module build.gradle. But could you tell me how can I check if my classes are getting obfuscated

Comment: you go into mapping file of android studio project then you check it out

Comment: No mapping file is getting generated. In my outputs folder, I have debug.aar as output. Any idea, why this is not getting generated

Comment: first of all you run your app in release mode

Comment: But this is an android library and not an app. I have gone through this link http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html but not understanding how to build in release mode.

Comment: just first of all generate  keystore and password then run in release version you seen mapping file and get result ok